# pass values from one html page to the other html page in PHONEGAP?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, parameter-passing

the answers i found the net and what i have implemented is as follows..

```
window.location.href=href='2ndpage.html?var id=results.rows.item(1).id';
```

*results.rows.item(1).id-**this the value i am getting it from the database---it would be the value of the id of the element in the DB.**

to get the value,i implemented this code..

```
 function onDeviceReady() 
    {var db =  window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("Database", "1.0", "Database",1000000); 
     console.log("processing onDeviceReady");
     db.transaction(getParameter,queryDB,errorCB);  
    }           

    function getParameter(paramName) 
    {   console.log("processsinggg parameter loop ");
    var searchString = window.location.search.substring(1),
        i, val, params = searchString.split("&");

         for (i=0;i<params.length;i++) {
                val = params[i].split("=");
            if (val[0] == paramName) {
            return unescape(val[1]);
        }
    console.log("valueeesss: "+val[1]);

  }return null;
}
```

**it process till this loop and stops... thinking i havent called the other functions..i called queryDB();**

when it processed queryDB in the code

```
function queryDB(tx) 
{       tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM table_name', [], querySuccess, errorCB);
        console.log("processing queryDB");
}
```

it says as tx is not defined..

i tried printing the output...o/p was..

```
results.rows.item(1).id
```

which i found difficult implementing it...**probably could be because of my mistake too..but....**

the other method i tried was the **FORM method**

```
<form name="2ndpart"  method="post">
id: <input type="hidden" name="id">
<input type="submit" value="results.rows.item(0).id">
</form>
```

and in the second page,i gave

```
function getUrlVars() {
var vars = {};
var parts = window.location.href.replace(/[?&]+([^=&]+)=([^&]*)/gi,function(m,key,value) {
    vars[key] = value;
});
return vars;
```

}

it did not go the 2nd page it self..as it said was not a function.

which is the right method and the easiest to implement?